# Among the conjugates, which complex number satisfies the equation of straight line

Tags: complex-numbers

The equation of a straight line in complex plane is 
$\bar a *z + \bar z *a= D$ .....[1] 
 where D $\in R$ and $a , \bar a$ is complex. Here the complex $z$ lies on line and $\bar z$ is conjugate of $z$.

---

The question arises, that how do we identify whether $z$ lies on the line or $ \bar z $ lies on the line; (although here we **explicitly** know it's $z$ by derivations.). It becomes tough to do so especially when the equation is not given explicitly in terms of $z$ and $\bar z$. 

More clearly, let $ p = a $ and $q = \bar a$ ;also let $ z = m $ and $ \bar z = n$. And then the line equation looks like 
$ pm + qn =D$
where p,m,q,n are complex and D is still real.  
Now let this be the equation given to us and we don't know whether $m$ is $ z$ or $ m$ is $\bar z$ (refer eqn [1]). But it is just known that $m $ and $n $ are conjugate. All we know is one of m or n lies on line. How do we identify which lies on line - m or n?

Like, if we are given that a complex number , say $ z_1 $ , satisfies the above equation of line. 
Then what should we substitute as $ z_1 $. Is it $m = z_1$ or $n = z_1 $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the fact that in the equation $pm + qn = D$ you have to decide $m$ is $z$. The equation is symmetric in $m$ and $n$ with corresponding $p$ and $q$. If you decide that $m$ is $z$ then the the equation is one equation of a line, and if you decide that $n$ is $z$ then the equation is for the line of conjugates or the other line.

Comment: so we have write the equation of line explicitly in terms of $z$ and $\bar z$. otherwise we will be unable to decide 'coz of the symmetry of equation.